# RegEx for matching MongoDB strings

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, regex-lookarounds

I'm using mongoose and have a large quantity of objects like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5bfeb4aa0a49bf3d84d885b5"),
"category" : [ 
    "Cult", 
    "Space Opera"
],
"actors" : [ 
    "David Prowse in the role of Darth Vader", 
    "Mark Hamill as Luke Skywalker", 
    "Carrie Fisher as Leia Organa", 
    ...
],
"title" : "Star Wars",
"description" : ".....",
"rating" : 4.65,
"__v" : 0
```

}

I need to find all the films that matches with my array of actors

for example: `["David Prowse", "Mark Hamill", "Carrie Fisher"]`

Using this array one of films should be **Star Wars** but in the film object there aren't clean actor names so probably need to match with regex or something like that to match by substring (case insensitive).

My actual query return always empty array of documents   ----------

```
let arrayOfqueries = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfActors.length; i++) {
        arrayOfqueries.push({$regex: ".*" + arrayOfActors[i] + ".*", $options: "i"});
    }

    Utils.searchFilms({
        "actors": {
            "$all": arrayOfqueries
        }
    }).then((docs) => {
        console.log(docs)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35321754/4302328

Comment: @the_mahasagar works, but it search now all the documents with one of my array of actors.. It should return the document only if all of my actors match with the document's actors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that a simple capturing group might suffice here. Then, based on Fanpark solution, your code might look like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfActors.length; i++) {
  arrayOfqueries.push(new RegExpr("(" + arrayOfActors[i] + ")"))
}
```

If that did not work, we can try other expressions such as:

```
(?:[\s\S]*)(David Prowse)(?:[\s\S]*)
```

and our code might look like:

```
arrayOfqueries.push(new RegExpr("(?:[\s\S]*)(" + arrayOfActors[i] + ")(?:[\s\S]*)"))
```

Also, metachars should be escaped.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Rzg8W9/1)

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression should be

```
for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfActors.length; i++) {
  arrayOfqueries.push(new RegExpr("\b" + arrayOfActors[i] + "\b"))
}
```