# Mongodb query starts with inside $in Query

Tags: mongodb

I want to write an `$in` query if column path starts with "/v1/user/1" or "/v1/user/2" then I want to select that particular document.

The sample document is as below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f8872b486aa9e79d71d9809"),
    "method" : "get",
    "path" : "/v1/user/1/details/"
}
```

I tried to create a query but getting syntax error because of "/"

```
db.user.find({ "path": { $in: [ /^/v1/user/1/ , /^/v1/user/2/ ] } })
```

Could some one please help how to write the query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB query $in with regex array of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321004/mongodb-query-in-with-regex-array-of-element), look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35321754/8987128) will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query was almost correct. You just missed to escape the `/`. Try below query.

```js
db.user.find({ "path": { $in: [ /^\/v1\/user\/1/ , /^\/v1\/user\/2/ ] } })
```